# Where is the Server Directory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to play Minecraft with my friends, but on a map I downloaded.

I always look up how to do it, and people say something about 
server directory. Where exactly is it located?

Comment: In Windows single player maps are saved in `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves`. So if you downloaded a minecraft map, put the map folder there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a server to do this (unless they're on your LAN, in which case loading the world and opening it to LAN should work).  You can get one from the Minecraft website for a basic server, or get a Spigot server for something a lot more advanced.

Assuming you just want a base server, you can set one up fairly easily, and this guide explains it better than I could https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

As for adding the world to that, you can just put it in the same directory as the server JAR itself, and configure the `server.properties` to reflect this.

The server directory is wherever the server JAR is executed from. Everything from here will be relative, so within this folder is the configuration file `server.properties`, the world save folders, and the where the logs are saved.

Comment: You're not actually answering the question as posed.  Where's the server directory?

Comment: Sorry, the server directory is wherever the server JAR is executed from.  Everything from here will be relative, so within this folder is where the world save folders should go, and the where the logs are saved

Comment: You should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on the same connection, you need to buy realms. If you are on the same connection, go to 1.8, open your world to LAN, let your friend goto multiplayer, and find the IP. Enter it in direct connect, for example, `125.1.975.23:` Go to any version you want, open a world, set to LAN, let your friend enter the numbers in the chat at the direct connect: `125.1.975.23: 03894`. Then, click connect.

Comment: Only the latest version works with Realms (not 1.8). You can't put a space between : and port. Also, you should tell how to find the IP (just "find the ip" doesn't help) and the "numbers" (the port).